# Change ROOT element name during XML to Java Object (JAXB) conversion

Tags: java, xml, xsd, namespaces, jaxb

I have a vendor who provides .xsd files and library which can process the data in XML format.

I cannot modify the root element name in the XSD file as these XSD files are subjected to change and it results in maintenance overhead.

Sample XSD file:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.xcv.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation" 
xmlns:op="http://www.xcv.com/schemas/MyOperation" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xsd:element name="CUSTOMER_V3_input">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ACCOUNT_NO" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
               <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                     <xsd:maxLength value="60"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
               </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="EMAIL_ADDR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
               <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                     <xsd:maxLength value="1023"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
               </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="FIRST_NAME" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
               <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                     <xsd:maxLength value="90"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
               </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Java class (CUSTOMERV3Input.java) generated using this schema:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {"accountno", "emailaddr", "firstname"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "CUSTOMER_V3_input"
)
public class CUSTOMERV3Input implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(
        name = "ACCOUNT_NO",
        required = true
    )
    protected String accountno;

    @XmlElement(
        name = "EMAIL_ADDR"
    )
    protected String emailaddr;

    @XmlElement(
        name = "FIRST_NAME"
    )
    protected String firstname;


    public CUSTOMERV3Input() {
    }

    public String getACCOUNTNO() {
        return this.accountno;
    }

    public void setACCOUNTNO(String value) {
        this.accountno = value;
    }

    public String getEMAILADDR() {
        return this.emailaddr;
    }

    public void setEMAILADDR(String value) {
        this.emailaddr = value;
    }

    public String getFIRSTNAME() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFIRSTNAME(String value) {
        this.firstname = value;
    }
}
```

I use the following code to convert POJO to XML String:

```
public static String jaxbObjectToXML(Object payload) {
    String xmlString = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(payload.getClass());
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // To format XML
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        m.marshal(payload, sw);
        xmlString = sw.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlString;
}
```

The XML data generated is:

```
<CUSTOMER_V3_input xmlns="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation">
    <ACCOUNT_NO>123147174283024</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FIRST_NAME>Bharath</FIRST_NAME>
</CUSTOMER_V3_input>
```

But, the library expects the root tag to be  instead of

```
public String makeRequest(String inputXmlString, 
                           OperationType type, 
                           String transactionId) 
        throws XXXException {
```

String **inputXmlString** should be:

```
<data>
    <ACCOUNT_NO>123147174283024</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FIRST_NAME>Bharath</FIRST_NAME>
</data>
```

OR

```
<data xmlns="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation">
    <ACCOUNT_NO>123147174283024</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FIRST_NAME>Bharath</FIRST_NAME>
</data>
```

And the data returned is:

```
<data>
    <ACCOUNT_NO>123147174283024</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FIRST_NAME>Bharath</FIRST_NAME>
    <EMAIL_ADDR>retrieved@email.address.com</EMAIL_ADDR>
</data>
```

But to convert this to java object, I need to change the root element name and **add the namespace** **xmlns="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation"**

From: `<data>`
To: `<CUSTOMER_V3_input xmlns="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation">`

```
<CUSTOMER_V3_input xmlns="http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation">
    <ACCOUNT_NO>123147174283024</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FIRST_NAME>Bharath</FIRST_NAME>
    <EMAIL_ADDR>retrieved@email.address.com</EMAIL_ADDR>
</CUSTOMER_V3_input>
```

So that I can pass this XMLString to this method to convert it into Java Object

```
public static <T> T xmlToJaxbObject(String xmlString, Class<T> classOfT) {
    T object = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classOfT);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        object = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

I'm currently using String.replace() function to make these changes and I do not feel its the right way.

Any recommendations would help.

Comment: Why does the library expect a different element name?

Comment: I'd patch the XML schema. Maintaining the patch is not effort-intensive.

Comment: Try marshalling `new JAXBElement<CUSTOMERV3Input>(new QName("http://xmlns.xxx.com/MyVendor/schemas/MyOperation", "data", CUSTOMERV3Input.class, payload))`.